# How to make my Firebase Realtime Database rule work properly?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have two different rules for my Firebase Realtime database.
One enables only authenticated users to read and write, while the other one is more complex. It only enables authenticated users to read and write data from the "rooms" node, and it enables users to work only with their own data in the "users" node.
However, when I use the second rule, I get the following error for some reasons I don't know.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object

My two rules are:

```
{
"rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

{
"rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "rooms": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

My code which contains the error-causing line (3rd line):

```
void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
   if(auth.CurrentUser != null) {
        currentRoom = args.Snapshot.Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("currentRoom").Value.ToString(); //this line causes the error
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("rooms").Child(currentRoom).Child("members").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("type").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                // Handle the error...
            } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                charType = snapshot.Value.ToString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to do some things in the rules playground in Firebase, but I didn't manage to get a solution there.
The HandleValueChanged method is working with the users node:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to read the entire `users` node:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").ValueChange
```

But your security rules only allow a user read access to their own node:

```
{
"rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
```

Since the user doesn't have access to all of `/users`, reading from that node is rejected.

The problem is that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters), so they don't filter data on their own. Instead they merely ensure that the operations that the user performs don't conflict with the rules you've set for them. And since you didn't grant anyone read access to (all of) `/users`, the read is rejected.

In your case I'd highly recommend simply changing the code to only access the note that the user **does** have access to:

```
String uid = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId;
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").Child(uid).ValueChanged = ...
```

In some other cases you might be able to combine a query and security rules to accomplish your needs. The query only requests the data that the user has access to, and the security rules ensure that the query matches those rules. For more on this, see the documentation on [query based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules).